# How to properly load a Lua script in StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: lua, stackexchange.redis

In the [StackExchange.Redis docs for scripting](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Scripting), it says a LoadedLuaScript can be used to avoid retransmitting the Lua script to redis each time it is evaluated. It then gives an example where the script is loaded into the server. I assume this shouldn't be done everytime you call the script, so where should the scripts be loaded?

Scripts are not persitent if redis server is restarted, so how should this be handled? Should they be loaded in ConnectionRestored event of the ConnectionMultiplexer? Presumably you would need to store them in a ConcurrentDictionary?

Comment: Script loaded to the redis itself using `SCRIPT LOAD` command. This command returns sha1 hash, so this hash can be used with th `EVALSHA` command to call this script. In fact this script can be loaded by any one and your application can just use this hash.

Comment: Thanks, but I know this information. The question is about when and how to run the SCRIPT LOAD command. You could do it on app startup - but then what happens if redis is restarted?

Comment: From doc `The script is guaranteed to stay in the script cache forever`. Basic logic is just use EVALSHA and in case of `NOSCRIPT` error call SCRIPT LOAD and try again

Answer (score 3):

**StackExchange.Redis handles Lua script caching internally. Normally you don't have to care about loading Lua scripts manually to redis.**

StackExchange.Redis automatically transmits the Lua script to redis on the first call to 'ScriptEvaluate'. For further calls of the same script only the hash is used:

```
var prepared = LuaScript.Prepare(script);
prepared.Evaluate(someDb); // loads the script to redis and calls it

var prepared2 = LuaScript.Prepare(script);
prepared2.Evaluate(someDb); // calls the script by it's hash
```

LoadedLuaScript might be useful for edge cases like loading without executing.

I also clarified the [official doku](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Scripting.html).

**Background information**

The library tries to call the script by it's hash and if the script is missing it gets a NOSCRIPT error and then transmits the script.

See ScriptEvalMessage:GetMessages in https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/main/src/StackExchange.Redis/RedisDatabase.cs

The behavior is also discussed and explained in the official StackExchange.Redis github repo:

- https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1246
- https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1371

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you. Also, sum up your answer in case the link stops working in the future.

Comment: Thank you @Elydasian for your feedback. I extended the answer,

Comment: If `LuaScript` is a new instance will be it still evaluated as a loaded script to the server?